# MDX query for nestings tops

Tags: mdx

Help with mdx query plz (Essbase 11.1.1)
I have 3 dimensions

```
[YEAR]
[SF]
[OPR_KIND]
```

1 level hierarchy for all

```
Measure: [Accounts].[FCT_OPR_SUM]
```

I have to find:
top 2 years, for each year 3 top SF, and for each SF 1 top OPR_KIND

for 1 nested top I do:

```
WITH
SET top2Year as 'TopCount( [YEAR].Generations(2).MEMBERS,2)'
SELECT {[Accounts].[FCT_OPR_SUM]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
generate(top2Year,
crossjoin( top2Year,topcount( [SF].Generations(2).MEMBERS,3)
)
)
} 
ON ROWS
FROM cube1f.cube1f
```

How to do for 2 or more nested tops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with something close to this:

```
Generate(TopCount([YEAR].Generations(2).MEMBERS, 2, [Accounts].[FCT_OPR_SUM]), 
   {[YEAR].CurrentMember} * Generate(TopCount([SF].Generations(2).MEMBERS, 3, [Accounts].[FCT_OPR_SUM]), 
           {[SF].CurrentMember} * TopCount('your OPR_KIND set', 1, [Accounts].[FCT_OPR_SUM])
   )
)
```